# Trying to render two spaces between sentences in an HTML error message

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I know that browsers strip out extra spaces after a single space.  I generally use "`&nbsp;`" to include a second space between sentences in my HTML.

Anyway, I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 and am trying to display an error message that's being injected into the page via a view model (as opposed to being coded directly into the HTML template). When I add "`&nbsp;`" to the error string that I'm putting into the view model, I end up getting "`&amp;nbsp;`" in the resulting web page, I assume because MVC 3 HTML encodes the final rendering of the view.

Anyone know a way to get around this so that I can get back my beloved double spacing between sentences? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Html.Raw()` in the view or change your view model from a `string` an `HtmlString`. Either way will bypass the HTML encoding. As long as you are sure this will be a "safe" string to render, it should be fine.